# Match "/" if its not immediately followed by "(" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried a lot of things, like the following:

```
\/(!?\()
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to use `(?!data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got many things wrong with your regex `/(!?()`.

`/` is not escaped. Negative look ahead syntax is wrong. Should be `(?!)`. `(` is not escaped.

Try with `\/(?!\()`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE5zL1/1)

Comment: Thanks, your worked. Mine was worse than it seemed because I didn't put it as code.

Comment: You don't need to escape the forward slash in raw regex `\/(?!\()`.

Comment: @sln: Care to point out the difference between my solution and **actual correct answer**  ?

Comment: Sure. I updvoted @JordanHendrix answer because his answer has an explanation of a lookahead, not just a syntax correction. Your answer has an error `/ is not escaped` _and_ it shouldn't be when showing a raw regex. Regex is %90 portable. Adding unnecessary escapes in a raw context is confusing and should be avoided. Jordan escaped his within the context of a delimited regex, you didn't.

Comment: Guessing, assuming that OP knows regex and only need correction in syntax my solution was concise to his needs.

Answer (score 1):

The following matches x only if x is followed by y:

```
x(?=y)  

/\/(?!\()/
```

Regex Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp